# Is it possible to have a placeholder in the cell.detailTextLabel of a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

By place holder I mean what you would get if you have a textfield ...

```
 UITextField *myTextField;
 myTextField.placeholder = @"Enter your name";
```

I believe detailTextLabel being a textLabel does not have the placeholder property so I am guessing the answere would be no. I would have to use a custom cell with a UITextField.

Thanks for any suggestions.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UITextField`'s placeholder is text that is shown when the field is empty and the user is not editing it.

The detail text label is a `UILabel`.  A `UILabel` doesn't support user editing, so there is no reason for it to have a `placeholder` property.  You can just set its text color to gray as Patrick S. suggests, if you want it to look like placeholder text.

However, if you want detail text that is editable, you will need to add your own `UITextField` to the cell's `contentView` and use that text field *instead of* the `detailTextLabel`.  Then you can set your text field's `placeholder` property.

Comment: You are of course right on the money. I realize now that this was a stupid question. Using a custom cell with a UITextField in it is the the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option might be:

```
if([UItextView.text length] == 0)
   {
       UItextView.text = @"placeholder";
       UItextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
       UItextView.tag = 0;
   }
```

Serves the same purpose.

Comment: Actually doing it this way is not the same. The field then actually has text in it which must be overwritten or deleted by the user, and handled by code if the user doesn't enter anything. A true placeholder is really a blank text field displaying the placeholder. Easy to handle and not confusing to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Change the placeholder text font in the textfield

Create a subclass of UITextField and overwrite the drawPlaceholderInRect:

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]];
}
```

Comment: An interesting approach, but I am not sure I understand exactly how to do what you are suggesting. I have made the custome cell and it is working the way I want. Thanks.